# SQl Command to find aggregate of total sales for distinct items within a period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the total sales made for distinct Items within specific period.

For instance, I have several items sold in a day, I want the cumulative total of each itme sold for that day and not just picking it one after the other as it was saved to the database.

Below is what I have presently.

| ItemName | Price | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nokia | 250 | 2 |
| Samsung | 300 | 2 |
| Nokia | 250 | 4 |
| Nokia | 250 | 2 |
| Samsung | 300 | 2 |
| Nokia | 250 | 3 |

Instead for it to be listing each item separately, I want it to pick an item and then add the quantities for the item together as below

| ItemName | Price | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nokia | 250 | 11 |
| Samsung | 300 | 4 |

The code I have tried is this:

```
"SELECT Order_Date,ItemName,qty,price 
 FROM tblOrderDetails 
 WHERE [Order_date] BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
ORDER BY order_date"
```

Is there a better way this can be done both using SQL and LINQ

I have also tried the below SQL Command but it keeps bringing error that the Order_Date must be part of the Group BY

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(Product_Name), SUM(qty) AS Qty, Order_date 
FROM tblOrderDetails WHERE [Order_date] BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate group by product_id, Order_date 
order by Order_date
```

Comment: Please add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text. Don’t link to images

Comment: Your images/output do not reflect your code.

Comment: @NickW, I have included the table

Comment: @PeterSmith, I removed the other information like cashier and amount as what I actually need to change is the Productname and Qty

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY`, perhaps? Can you please tag the RDBMS you're using in this case? Answers can vary quite materially between each.

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `SUM` will get you what you want

Comment: @esqew Yes. I have tried the GROUP BY but issues persist. I have also edited the question to contain another SQL command I have tried.

Comment: @PeterSmith, I have tried that, I posted an edit already and the error persist..

Comment: That's  because you have `order_date` in your output in your query but not in your example. If you want it in your output then add it to the output. I will post a second script reflecting that

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it acts over the whole resultset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```sql
SELECT product_id, Product_Name, Price, SUM(qty * Price) as amount, SUM(qty) AS Qty, Order_date 
FROM tblOrderDetails 
WHERE Order_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
group by product_id, Product_Name, Order_date, price 
order by Order_date
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, It sums up the Qty as wanted but the unit price and Amount is left out. Like let us say Sum(Qty) is 5, Price is 500, the Amount will be 2500 that way, Can this be extended? Thank you

Comment: You just add other columns as I edited the answer

Comment: See Error:   Column 'tblOrderDetails.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add Price column in group by, edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works fine for selecting the price and also sum up the Qty but the Amount, is not correct. I think that has to be hard coded or is it possible to do arithmetic with Select statement like saying Amount =(Qty * Price)?. I want to accept this as the answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes `Amount = SUM(qty * price)` would work, I edited answer. Sorry I didn't realize minor details in answer, but as you see all columns that are displayed in `select`, `where` and `order by` need to be also in `group by` if you use an `aggregate`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your time.. Wait... Should it be SUM(Qty*Price)? and not something else. I mean what that sum is doing

Comment: If you don't use `sum` you will need to add qty column to `group by` and that will result in all rows, because you divide the `group by` in each row that have different qty. So in theory you can use `amount = price * qty` and it will give you the right answer, but in your situation it would be better to use `sum()`, maybe it will add to the time it takes for the query to run, but as far as I can think now use `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (not tested)

```
SELECT  ItemName, price, SUM(qty) AS Qty
FROM tblOrderDetails 
WHERE [Order_date] BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
GROUP BY ItemName, price
```

Not sure where `order_date` plays a part other than in selection, but to match your script ...

```
SELECT  [Order_date], ItemName, price, SUM(qty) AS Qty
FROM tblOrderDetails 
WHERE [Order_date] BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
GROUP BY [Order_date], ItemName, price
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am checking it out..